# Visual Basic RegEx Help - Extracting and replacing paths

Tags: regex, vb.net, vba

I have file paths such as:

```
' Any number of folders before and after the Project name
C:\a\b\c\d\Project1\e\f\g\somefile.someextension'
```

How would I:

1. Extract only the path before the project name?

   `C:\a\b\c\d\`
2. Extract the path after the project name?

   `\e\f\g\somefile.someextension`

Note: Of course given the filename.

Would `Split` be better or some complicated [regex](/questions/tagged/regex)?

Comment: Is this VBA or .Net? If .Net, I suggest you look into ``System.IO.Path`` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx

Comment: This is especially important because VB.NET does not have regular expression support, but .NET does.

Answer (score 2):

Updated for a wildcard test using `InStr`

```
Sub ParsMe()
    Dim strTest As String
    Dim strnown As String
    Dim arrStr() As String
    Dim strOut As String
    Dim lngFirst As Long
    Dim lngStart As Long
    Dim lngEnd As Long
    strTest = "C:\a\b\c\d\Project1\e\f\g\somefile.someextension"
    strKnown = "Project"
    lngFirst = InStr(strTest, strKnown)
    If lngFirst > 0 Then
        lngEnd = InStr(lngFirst, strTest, "\")
        lngStart = InStrRev(strTest, "\", lngFirst)
    MsgBox "Start path:= " & Left$(strTest, lngStart) & vbNewLine & "End path:=" & Right$(strTest, Len(strTest) - lngEnd + 1), vbInformation, "Found:= " & Mid$(strTest, lngStart + 1, lngEnd - lngStart - 1)
    Else
        MsgBox strKnown & " not found in " & strTest
    End If
End Sub
```

For a simple split use `Split`, a Regex adds no additional value here. Something like tis

```
Option Base 0
Sub ParseMe()
    Dim strTest As String
    Dim strKnown As String
    Dim arrStr() As String
    strTest = "C:\a\b\c\d\Project1\e\f\g\somefile.someextension"
    strKnown = "Project1"
    arrStr = Split(strTest, strKnown)
    If UBound(arrStr) = 0 Then
        MsgBox strKnown & " not found", vbCritical
    Else
        MsgBox "path before is " & arrStr(0) & vbNewLine & "path after is " & arrStr(1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How about if the project name is not given but has a prefix 'Project'?

Comment: In that case you would need to use 'InStr' or a Regex. Aren't "false" matches a possiblity then?

Comment: @user622469 I have added an update above to handle your new sample